# A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'

Tags: flutter

The Error Says:

A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'GoogleSignInAccount

Here is my code:

```
bool isLoggedIn = false;
bool showProgressIndicator = false;
late GoogleSignInAccount userObj;
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();


Future loginUser() async {
    googleSignIn.signIn().then((userData) {
      setState(() {
        isLoggedIn = true;
        userObj = userData;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either make `GoogleSignInAccount` nullable by changing definition to :

> GoogleSignInAccount? userObj;

Or tell flutter `userData` will not be null by adding `!`, like:

> userObj = userData!;

Comment: @SAch can you accept the answer please, if it worked ?

Comment: Sorry, that would be against the guidelines. I only asked you to accept because the answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for google sign. It will work perfectly.

final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
await googleUser?.authentication;

```
  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential userresult =
      (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential));
  User? user = userresult.user;
```